# My script works only when when there is an alert function in the script

Tags: javascript, jquery

My script  works only  when i have an alert function in it.

Well I  want to scroll my div to bottom . I researched but yet, my script does not execute without an `alert` function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#display-message").animate({ scrollTop: $('#display-message').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat-log">
  <div id="display-message">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to animate body like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#display-message").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```